# Angular Primeng sidebar is transparent

Tags: angular, primeng, sidebar

I'm currently on an Angular 7 project with PrimeNg v7.
I want to use the PrimeNg sidebar module but I can't manage to remove the transparent background and the shadow does not appear when it's open :
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CINHx.png)

I want it to be just like on the primeNg website :
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ympDV.png)

Here is my code : appcomponent.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" [baseZIndex]="10000">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</p-sidebar>

<button type="text" (click)="display = true" pButton icon="pi pi-plus" label="Show"></button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SidebarModule,
    ButtonModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: 'pronosticServiceType', useClass: environment.pronosticServiceType}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

sidebar.component.html :

```
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/Pronostics">Pronostics</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you really want to do? do you want to remove the modal mood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to include **primeNg global styles** into your project, if you use `angular-cli` you can do that in `angular.json` file into `styles` array of your project:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  //...
],
```

If it won't help please leave a comment.

Comment: You are totally right this should work, but if that will not work he can use `npm i primeng`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed !